# Can I load more than one model to activate with AR marker with AFrame?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

Following the tutorials at https://aframe.io/blog/arjs/ and the like. All are great at getting one model to show up with one marker. I'm looking for an example of how to:

1. Use different markers to load different models. Are they different scenes?
2. Load (or enabled display of) multiple models, one marker.

This is the case where I load a 'base' model, and then define some animation to bring other objects into the same space over time. I found the animation tutorial, not sure how to set this up with AR camera.

Does anyone have such examples?

Answer (score 1):

Anything You throw inside the `<a-marker>` should appear once the marker is detected.

So You should create a normal scene with the models appearing and just copy paste it in the ar tags.

If you have problems creating a scene where a model appears when an animation ends, then you should make another question (or check search for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575681/how-to-start-an-a-frame-animation-by-an-animationend-javascript-function))

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the tutorial below - it shows multi-marker use in AR.js? 
https://medium.com/arjs/area-learning-with-multi-markers-in-ar-js-1ff03a2f9fbe

Comment: I did not, thanks. That one is about using multiple markers to anchor one object though. I'm looking for kinda the opposite: one marker to anchor multiple objects (which are in different files)